# How to create alias to kill processes running on a TCP/IP port?

Tags: bash, alias, kill

**What I have:**

```
alias killport='sudo kill -9 `sudo fuser -n tcp $1 2> /dev/null`'
```

**Problem:**

Running e.g. `killport 8000` doesn't appear to work, though. However, simply running...

```
sudo kill -9 `sudo fuser -n tcp 8000 2> /dev/null`
```

... DOES work. I can't figure out where I'm messing up.

The major difference between the working and non-working versions as far as I can see is that the aliased version involves a variable, and is executed by the shell for me.... But maybe someone has seen this kind of problem before and knows right where to look.

Comment: [Bash Aliases do not support arguments](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html). Use a function

Comment: Hm. Well, that'd do it. I guess I'll just write a script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a function instead an alias, becaue aliases don't support parameters, make something like that:

```
killport(){ 

sudo kill -9 $(sudo fuser -n tcp $1 2> /dev/null);

}
```

Now put this function in your bash configuration file, eg ~/.bashrc and then run:

```
source  ~/.bashrc
```

And you're done

HTH